# spring data JPA deletion

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am getting a foreign key violation when I try to delete a record.

I have this record:

```
@Entity
public class Parent {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long parentId;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "childId")
    private Child child;
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Child")
public class Child {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long childId;


    public Long getOperatoryId() {
        return id;
    }
```

When I try to delete the child, I get a key violation because there are some parent records that point to the children.  I thought I could delete the parent first, then go delete the children as:

parentRepository.delete(parent)

but I get an error that the property id doesn't exist on child.  Is this because the child id is named childId and not id?

Answer (score 0):

Here I worked on similar example what did you asked for. Customize it based on your need.

- SQL Server table create query

  ```
   CREATE TABLE "DBO"."Parent"(
   Parent_Id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
   Parent_Name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL)

   CREATE TABLE "DBO"."Child"(
   Child_Id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
   Child_Name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
   Parent_Ref_Id int not null,
   CONSTRAINT FK_Parent_Ref_Id FOREIGN KEY (Parent_Ref_Id) REFERENCES Parent(Parent_Id)
  )
  ```
- Spring data JPA code

### Parent Entity

```
    @Entity(name = "Parent")
    @Table(name = "Parent")
    public class Parent {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "Parent_Id")
    private long parentId;

    @Column(name = "Parent_Name")   
    private String parentName;

    //cascade = {CascadeType.REMOVE} OR orphanRemoval = true    
    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL},orphanRemoval = true,fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy="parentInfo")    
    private Child childInfo;

    public long getParentId() {
        return parentId;
    }

    public void setParentId(long parentId) {
        this.parentId = parentId;
    }

    public String getParentName() {
        return parentName;
    }

    public void setParentName(String parentName) {
        this.parentName = parentName;
    }

    public Child getChildInfo() {
        return childInfo;
    }

    public void setChildInfo(Child childInfo) {
        this.childInfo = childInfo;
    }
    }
```

### Child Entity

```
@Entity(name = "Child")
@Table(name = "Child")
public class Child {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "Child_Id")
    private int childId;

    @Column(name = "Child_Name")
    private String childName;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "Parent_Ref_Id", referencedColumnName = "Parent_Id")
    private Parent parentInfo;

    public int getChildId() {
        return childId;
    }

    public void setChildId(int childId) {
        this.childId = childId;
    }

    public String getChildName() {
        return childName;
    }

    public void setChildName(String childName) {
        this.childName = childName;
    }

    public Parent getParentInfo() {
        return parentInfo;
    }

    public void setParentInfo(Parent parentInfo) {
        this.parentInfo = parentInfo;
    }

}
```

### Child Repo Code

```
public interface ChildRepo extends CrudRepository<Child,Long> {

}
```

### Parent Repo Code

```
public interface ParentRepo extends CrudRepository<Parent,Long> {
    Parent findByParentId(long id);
}
```

### Controller Code

```
@Autowired
private final ParentRepo parentRepo;
....

private void save() {
        //Save the parent
        Parent p = new Parent();
        p.setParentId(1);
        p.setParentName("Parent1");
        Child c = new Child();
        c.setChildId(1);
        c.setChildName("Child1");
        c.setParentInfo(p);
        p.setChildInfo(c);
        parentRepo.save(p);

        //delete the parent and child as well
        Parent p1 = parentRepo.findByParentId(1);
        parentRepo.delete(p1);
    }
```